# Split Too Long String

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string like in the following picture:
[image]

I'm Consuming an API which take this large string in json like this `{"data" : "the large string which in the picture"}`
So i wanted to develop it and send the string in 2 request but when i was trying to use `Length / 2` i got the half of that large string but not completed row like in the follow picture: 
[image]

i wanna get the half of that string with completed row to avoid timing out in requests

the code which gave me that result:

```
            DataPart1.data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataByte.Take(dataByte.Length / 2).ToArray());

            DataPart2.data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataByte.Skip(DataPart1.data.Count()).ToArray()).ToString();
```

Comment: please post the code that you have tried!

Comment: What is the length of the string?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko huge and not constant

Comment: you can count the lines and then make divide by 2 so you'll get half of your long string

Comment: @er-shoaib in string there's no lines

Comment: Easiest way would be to split the string by newline delimiter, and then join it join half of the array together and send it, but this would be very very slow. What about finding a half of string and then finding next newline character in loop?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i posted the code which i tried

Comment: i saw in your second screen shot you there is lines in your text so I'll suggest you for lines

Comment: @er-shoaib in my picture just string from the compiler if i had toooooooooooo big screen would be shown as one line

Comment: @Mailosz: Also my first idea, but there is a faster way. Cut the string in 2 halfs. Search last linebreak in first string. Cut it there and put the remaining in front of the second string.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen Right, it would be faster and in some cases easier to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the exact index you want to split the string at, you might want to try looking up for the closest `\r\n` next to the middle of the string using the `String.IndexOf(string value, int startIndex)` method.
The code would look something like

```
var str = "1,2,3,4\r\n5,6,7,8\r\n9,10,11,12";
var half = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("\r\n", str.Length / 2));
```

Which results in `"1,2,3,4\r\n5,6,7,8"`

You might want to add some additional validation for cases like if the middle of the string is within the last line or if line delimiter used is other than `\r\n`.

Comment: I like this, this is fast and simple and does not need a loop, like my idea would.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the input string can be a varying length, it may be better to batch the requests to a known length rather than simply splitting to half.

```
int REQUEST_SIZE = 1024;
string requestDelimiter = "\r\n";
int requestStart = 0;
int requestEnd = 0;

while(requestStart < dataByte.Length)
{
   // Sending loop
   int batchLength = requestStart+REQUEST_SIZE;
   if (requestStart+batchLength > dataByte.Length)
   {
      // Cover for when the end of the string exceeds batchLength
      // Ensure that the batchLength is adjusted to be within the string length
      batchLength = dataByte.Length - requestStart;
   }
   requestEnd = dataByte.IndexOf(requestDelimiter, batchLength, StringComparison.Ordinal);
   var requestData = dataByte.Substring(requestStart, requestEnd - requestStart);
   // TODO: process requestData

   requestStart = requestEnd;
}
```

The above code breaks the request into 1024 character chunks.

Please note: Untested code - there might be typos.

Comment: why the above answer break i tried it on the string which in the pic in the question and it worked

Comment: I cannot recall off the top of my head if `batchLength = dataByte.Length - requestStart;` should be `batchLength = dataByte.Length - requestStart -1;`.  But as I said - Untested code.  It's more a proof of concept that a tested code sample.

Comment: @AbdelrhmanElsaid It's variable I renamed to batchLength.  Corrected.

Comment: please when you be free test your code because i got an exception at ```                   var requestData = DataPart1.data.Substring(requestStart, requestEnd);
```
`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length'`

Comment: the second argument of the `string.Substring(int index, int length)` should be the length rather than index. That is, `var rquestData = dataByte.Substring(requestStart, requestEnd - requestStart);`